# letter has been sent to office by yesterday

Tags: word-usage

I just want to say, the letter already send to our head office yesterday. Please advise the correct usage

letter has been sent to office by yesterday - this usage is correct or not? please advise

Comment: I would advise for using *was sent*, and no *by* here.

Answer (score 1):

Stylistically, "was sent" would be better ("has been" would indicate more recently than yesterday.  As soon as you give a definite time [yesterday, on the 10th of January, last week, last month, etc.], "has been" is not the most felicitous choice).

Answer (score 1):

Logically, if the letter was sent yesterday, it has already been sent, so it's unnecessary to use both "yesterday" and "already" in the one sentence. It would be sufficient to say either:

> The letter has been sent to our office already.

[or]

> The letter was sent to our office yesterday.

Note that "has been" is generally used for a past event with no specific timeframe, whereas if the timing is specified (i.e. yesterday) it would be better to use "was". It's also a bit unusual - though not incorrect - to say "*by* yesterday"; using "by" changes the meaning slightly, indicating that it was sent some time in the past and no later than yesterday. If you want to emphasise the indeterminate timing, it would be more common to say "no later than yesterday".

Notwithstanding the above, using both "yesterday" and "already" would be appropriate if you wanted to emphasise the fact that it had been sent, for example as a polite way of indicating annoyance or frustration. You could say:

> The letter has already been sent to our office, yesterday.